# Strange comma operator behaviour

Tags: c++, operators

```
void foo() {
   int a[5], c = 2;
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      a[i] = 0;
   int res = (c--, a[c]++, c++) + (c++, a[c]--, c--);
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      cout << i << ": " << a[i] << endl;
}
```

The code above will print:

```
0 : 0
1 : 1
2 : -1
3 : 0
4 : 0
```

Instead of:

```
0 : 0
1 : 1
2 : 0
3 : -1
4 : 0
```

This is so because the operations order in generated code is the following:

```
// first parentheses
c--;
a[c]++;
// second parentheses
c++;
a[c]--;
// and only then the last operation
res = c++ + c--;
```

The question is: why operations do not run as expected (i.e. all three operations in one parentheses and then all three operations in other)?

Comment: Operands of `+` are **not** ordered. There's no saying of which is computed first.

Comment: @n.m. Or even that one _is_ computed first.  The compiler can compute part of one, then part of another, then return to the first, etc.  (Which is apparently what is happening here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of operations is not guarenteed in between sequence points. An sequence point is generally found at a semi-colon.

Wouldn't `a[c-1]++;` be better than `(c--, a[c]++, c++)` anyway? Why write to main RAM a new value for `c` 4 times when you don't keep the value for some other calculation?

Comment: The comma operator is also a sequence point.